# CSS float left - some bugs

Tags: css, css-float

I use wordpress nextgen gallery and all images are showing by float left side by side.

But i ses strange bug: http://oksanaseregina.com/portfolio/weddings/?album=1&gallery=16

Can you help me, why the spaces appears?[image]

Comment: Yes! http://oksanaseregina.com/portfolio/weddings/?album=1&gallery=16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `height` to your `.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box` DIV .Write like this:

```
.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box{
  float:left;
  height:150px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it's not exactly a bug: this behaviour happens because your `6th` image is 129px tall instead of 130px, so when the `7th` image has to float left it just float until it reaches the edge of the 5th image

so to prevent this you have to set all images with the same height or you avoid using float in favour of `display: inline-block` so to prevent this kind of issues